# AADSTS65001: invalid grant when trying to authorize user via MSAL PublicClientApplication

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-ad-msal

I have a web app (React app) which can authenticate the user.
The problem is that i'm seeing an AAD error:

```
invalid_grant: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID "My app client ID". Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.
```

Now, under Azure AAD --> App Registrations --> API Permissions, I am seeing the following permission (which is what im trying to use). But I noticed that the status of the permission does **NOT say it has been granted.**

[image]

**Question:**

Is this the reason/culprit for this error i am seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the most common reason for this error which you are seeing.

Comment: So now im using an AAD registered app with 3 scopes. All 3 scopes are marked as "No admin consent required" AND Status says "Granted". Yet, still, I am seeing "invalid_grant: AADSTS65001" when i try to obtain a silent access token for scopes: ["User.Read", "user_impersonation"]. Any ideas?

Comment: How is the grant being obtained?Can you provide details for it?